# Why does freecodecamp not let my while loop continue?

Tags: javascript, loops, infinite-loop, infinite

```
function checkRange(num, temp) {
  for (var i = 1; i < num; i++) {
    console.log(temp % i, i, temp);
    if (temp % i != 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

function smallestCommons(arr) {
  arr.sort((a, b) => {return a > b})
  var two = [arr[1]];
  var check = false;
  while (check == false) {
    two.push(two[two.length - 1] + arr[1])
    if (checkRange(arr[1], two[two.length - 1]) == true) {
      check = true;
      return two[two.length - 1];
    }
  }
  console.log(two);
  // not sure what to do with this
  return two[two.length - 1];
}


smallestCommons([1, 13]);
```

So I do realize that it's probably an infinite loop, but I would like to know why this is happening.

My code is not working for:

smallestCommons([1, 13]) should return 360360.

smallestCommons([23, 18]) should return 6056820.

The code works with the following steps:

Get lower number as first index (sort)

Make a loop that will keep adding the last index with arr[1] and validate if every number counting up to arr[0] can be divided evenly for the last element of the array.

[reference](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/intermediate-algorithm-scripting/smallest-common-multiple)

Comment: It appears that you never set `check` to `true`.  Exiting the loop therefore requires `(countDown(arr[1], two[two.length - 1]) == true` to evaluate to `true`.

Comment: As an aside, the function `countDown()` could be named better.  I'm pretty sure its purpose is not to count down.

Comment: Compare your code with [this](https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-math-exercise-10.php).

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm not sure how to incorporate this. Also note, I am very bad at math.

Comment: That's not a good sign.  But you don't really need to understand a lot of math.  LCM is the smallest number that can be divided evenly by all inputs.  GCD is the largest number that divides all inputs evenly.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I understand the math just not how to use it

Comment: So just walk through the code at the link I posted, executing each step of the code in your mind.  You'll need to learn how to do this anyway.  See also https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my answer when I was learning:

```js
function checkall(arr, lcm) {
  let num1 = arr[0]
  let num2 = arr[1]
  // Get the start number
  let first = (num1 < num2) ? num1 : num2;
  // Get the end number
  let last = (num1 > num2) ? num1 : num2;
  while (first != last) {
    // Check if lcm is divisble
    if (lcm % first != 0) {
      // If not then get an lcm of the number and existing lcm
      lcm = getlcm(first, lcm)
    }
    // Increment first
    first++
  }
  // Return the end lcm
  return lcm
}

function smallestCommons(arr) {
  // Get the two numbers
  let num1 = arr[0]
  let num2 = arr[1]
  // Feed the array and lcm into the checkall function
  return checkall(arr, getlcm(num1, num2))
}

function getlcm(num1, num2) {
  // Get the minimum number out of both
  let min = (num1 > num2) ? num1 : num2;
  while (true) {
    // Check if a number is divisible by both
    if (min % num1 == 0 && min % num2 == 0) {
      // If matches, this is the lcm
      // Break the loop and return the lcm
      return min
      break;
    }
    // Increment the number
    min++;
  }
}


console.log(smallestCommons([1, 13]))
console.log(smallestCommons([23, 18]))
console.log(smallestCommons([2, 10]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out the reason it times out, is because it's not efficient and takes way too much loops.

Keshav's answer seems to take lots of loops too so I'm not really sure why it doesn't time out...